# Pass state from one component to another in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a Weather Application, and I need to seperate the Weather card into its own component. So far, while I had the Weather card in my `Weather.js` file it has been working good. But now I have seperated the Weather card into its own component but I cannot access the state.

This is my main component where I have my state:

```js
export default class Weather extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       error: null,
       isLoaded: false,
       items: [],
       selectedValue: ''
    };
 }
 
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=ca021cd2c43544e0be7112719202206&q=kosovo&days=3")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
       (result) => {
          this.setState({
             isLoaded: true,
             items: result
          });
       },
       (error) => {
          this.setState({
             isLoaded: true,
             error
          });
       }
    );
 }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    return (
      <WeatherCard items={this.state}/>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the other component that I am trying to use the state

```js
const WeatherCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Today</h2>
      <span>{this.props.items.location.country}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error that I get is: undefined has no properties

Comment: You shouldn't have `this` when accessing the props in functional components. `props` refers to the properties, that's why it's an argument to the functional components. So just `props.items.location.country`

Comment: @Jayce444 Now I am getting the "props.items.location is undefined" error message

Comment: Are you getting the response when you are hitting the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    return (
      <WeatherCard items={items}/>
    )
  }
```

And in your weather component

```
 const WeatherCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Today</h2>
      <span>{props.items.location.country}</span>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    return (
      <WeatherCard items={this.state}/>
    )
  }
```

change to

```
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    return (
      <WeatherCard items={items}/>
    )
  }
```

and

```
const WeatherCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Today</h2>
      <span>{this.props.items.location.country}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

change to this

```
  const WeatherCard = (props) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h2>Today</h2>
              <span>{props.items.location.country}</span>
            </div>
          )
        }
```